# AS3: Not possible to have getters and setters for same variable in different interfaces?

Tags: actionscript-3, interface, setter, getter

The following code seems to create an ambiguity for the compiler (please see error commented near the bottom). Is it not possible to have getters and setters split between interfaces?

```
public interface GetterInterface 
{
    function get test():int;
}

public interface SetterInterface 
{
    function set test(value:int):void;
}

public interface SplitTestInterface extends GetterInterface, SetterInterface
{

}

public class SplitTest implements SplitTestInterface
{

    public function SplitTest() 
    {

    }

    /* INTERFACE test.SetterInterface */

    public function set test(value:int):void 
    {

    }

    /* INTERFACE test.GetterInterface */

    public function get test():int 
    {
        return 0;
    }

}

//Somewhere...
var splitTest:SplitTestInterface = new SplitTest();
splitTest.test = 2; //Error: Property is read-only.
```

Comment: You can't extend more than one interface or class.

Comment: That's not true for interfaces. And from Adobe documentation (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f41.html): Interfaces can extend one or more other interfaces.

Comment: My guess then is that because the getter and setter methods are defined in separate interfaces they aren't related to eachother. Basically in your class that implements the interfaces with the getter and setter methods, your implementing the definitions of their respective interface. In your case your implementing the read only `test()` method from your `GetterInterface` and the write only test method from the `SetterInterface`.

Comment: If I'm right you shouldn't be able to set a value for `test` because the getter method and setter methods have negated eachother. It'd be interesting if that were true, of course I could be wrong and there might be a simpler explaination.

Comment: I'm not sure why they should be related to each other. Under the hood, the compiler should mangle those to something like setTest and getTest but, regardless, they are distinguishable. And this is only a problem for gets/sets. For instance, if I change those to actual setTest/getTest methods, there is no problem. I can work around it of course by not using get/sets in this case. It seems like a straight up compiler bug to me but I'd sure like to understand what rule.

Comment: BTW, languages like C# do explicitly bind those together for a single property under the hood (and semantically) but, there, you can use a protected keyword in the interface, giving the same effect I'd like here.

Comment: C# also lets you implement multiple interfaces containing methods with the same names.  ActionScript 3 doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 3):

I put together the following (which is all but identical to your code) and works fine for both the get and set method.

```
/* IGet.as */
package {
    public interface IGet 
    {
        function get test():int;
    }
}


/* ISet.as */
package {
    public interface ISet 
    {
        function set test(i:int):void;
    }
}


/* ISplit.as */
package {
    public interface ISplit extends IGet, ISet {
    }
}

/* SplitTest.as */
package {
    public class SplitTest implements ISplit {

        public function SplitTest() {
        }

        public function set test(i:int):void {
            trace("Set");
        }

        public function get test():int {
            trace("Get");
        }
    }
}
```

The following is on the maintimeline:

```
var foo:SplitTest = new SplitTest();
foo.test;
foo.test = 1;
```

And outputs:

```
Get
Set
```

Comment: Huh. Yeah, I don't see a relevant difference. Mine was actually in a "test" package but I moved it to the global package just to remove that difference and still no dice. May I ask what compiler version you are using?

Comment: Oh, I see. The difference is that you are not accessing through the interface (ISplit).

Comment: Yes good point. I tried:

`trace(foo is ISplit); // returns true`

`var a:Vector.<ISplit> = new Vector.<ISplit>();`
`a.push(foo);`

`a[0].test; // errors out`
`a[0].test = 2; // errors out`

I can't see around this. Unless your class SplitTest implements IGet and ISet directly.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting question.  Based on the output, it looks like the compiler doesn't really understand what's going on.  Using a custom compiler to call force the call in the player results in

```
Property SplitTestInterface::test not found on SplitTest and there is no default value.
```

So the answer is no.  It's not supported by the language, and it's not supported by the runtime.  That's good though, I would never want to see this in production code.

Edit: My test was messed up, actually it works fine in the runtime.

Comment: @Sean: Curious as to why you wouldn't want this capability.

Comment: This seems perfectly valid to me, particularly for a language that doesn't provide significant access control. One point would be to provide proper access with strong-typing. A specific example would be Placeable and Moveable. Placeable would have a location that can't be set once constructed (or at least without direct access to the class itself). Moveable would extend Placeable and should work in all functions that accept a Placeable but would add an interface to modifying the location (for functions that work with Moveables). Note that this is all doable if you don't use gets/sets.

Comment: Right, if you want to do that, define getX and setX.  An accessor is supposed to represent a single property.  You'll also confuse the IDE if you try to "go to declaration" for the property.

Comment: In that case, they probably *would* be the same property (same memory even), just with different access. However, I'm not sure I buy the "supposed to"; interfaces are interfaces so why would you make any assumptions about the internals?

Comment: I'm not talking about the in memory representation... that doesn't even make sense.  I'm talking about the interface.  The first one says 'An object implementing this interface has a read-only property "test"', the second says 'An object implementing this interface has a write-only property "test"'.  It makes sense that both of these conditions can't be satisfied by one class.

Comment: I'm seriously curious about where you get that idea. I'm new to AS and definitely don't know the full stack and the intentions at each level. I think what you say is true of something like C# where access is fully defined in one definition (though you can also override that behavior). AS explicitly separates gets/sets and, again, we're talking interfaces. Each interface has a given ability but certainly a class (or sub-interface) can have more caps than its individual interfaces.